# How background app like NT-service can work with MFA in Office 365

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, multi-factor-authentication

My NT-service on Windows use EWS API to access Office 365 accounts to perform some periodical job.
It's written in C++.
When customer install my app he selects user/password which NT-service uses to send EWS requests. User/password is saved in some conf-file in encrypted view.
Now Microsoft force to use MFA for Office 365.
Question is how background NT-service can pass MFA with additional SMS-code if it does not interact with user?
I read about app-pasword
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords

It works but they write "Your administrator may not allow you to use app passwords".
Also it adds problems to user to manage this app password.
Is any alternative solutions to use MFA from app which do not interact with user (like NT-services)?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register your app in your Exchange tenant and authenticate using a certificate - https://developermessaging.azurewebsites.net/2018/09/11/authenticating-against-exchange-web-services-using-certificate-based-oauth2-tokens/

No password prompt would ever be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found info that my current method to ask OAuth token also should work with EWS connection.
I use POST request to /<tenant_id>/oauth2/token
with grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&scope=%s
And I found that problem happens with Autodiscover request.
If I use outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx at once - all works.
So question is - if it's correct not to use Autodiscover for Office365 accounts?

Comment: Its okay not to use autodiscover with Office365 as the URL is static, the exceptions are the national tenants https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments and hybrid modern authentication but these are a minatory of clients.

Answer (score 0):

One easier way of handing this would be to use conditional MFA or Trusted IP's https://dirteam.com/sander/2020/07/07/todo-move-from-mfa-trusted-ips-to-conditional-access-named-locations/ to effectively allow your app to bypass it (given that it should be running in a trusted context).

TOTP (Time based One Time passwords) as a secondary factor is the most automatable eg https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2020/07/using-2-authentication-factors-for-mfa.html but I would recommend the first approach as this is going to be more reliable in the long term.

The Third option would be to use the Client Credentials flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview this gets you away from using a UserName and Password which is a more secure option. I would probably move away form EWS to the Graph API for this as you can further scope down the access in the Graph as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found info that my current method to ask OAuth token also should work with EWS connection.
I use POST request to /<tenant_id>/oauth2/token
with grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&scope=%s
And I found that problem happens with Autodiscover request.
If I use outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx at once - all works.
So question is - if it's correct not to use Autodiscover for Office365 accounts?